# how to explain to typescript that variable is always a string in generic class

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have the following class and interface definition:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

type KeysMatching<T, V> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T];

interface SearchListProps<T extends object, K extends KeysMatching<T, string>> {
    data: T[];
    sort_and_filter_key: K;
}

class SearchList<ItemDataT extends object, K extends KeysMatching<ItemDataT, string>> extends Component<SearchListProps<ItemDataT, K>> {

    constructor(props: SearchListProps<ItemDataT, K>) {
        super(props);

        const value = props.data[0][props.sort_and_filter_key]; // ItemDataT[K] -> should be string
    }
}

// exmple case: 

interface DataExample {
    name: string, 
    city: string,
    id: number,
    content: object
    // etc
}

const example_data: DataExample[] = [
    {
        name: "asd",
        city: "bcn",
        id: 1,
        content: {}
    },
    {
        name: "dkg",
        city: "nld",
        id: 2,
        content: {}
    }
];

<SearchList data={example_data} sort_and_filter_key={"city"}></SearchList>
```

As you can see commented in the code typescript thinks that value is of type `ItemDataT[K]` but it should be `string`.

Why? because the property `sort_and_filter_key` should only allow keys of which the value is a string due to the following generic expression: `K extends KeysMatching<T, string>`. But typescript doesn't seem to understand this.

The autocomplete does seem to understand see image below:
[image]
Since this picture clear only allows the two keys that are guaranteed to be strings.

How do i make tsc understand this also?
If anything is unclear please let me know so i can modify the question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would `ItemDataT[K]` be `string`? `ItemDataT` is defined as object. If it would be `Record<any, string>` (or another key type), then it would probably be a string.
Also, a more minimal example would be helpful.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the `K extends KeysMatching<T, string>` should force the value of `sort_and_filter_key`  to always be a string. I will update the question tomorrow so it is easier to test and see the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Markus I modified to question so it is as minimal and reproducible as possible.

Comment: If it is `string` why did you declare it as `T[]`? Why make its type a generic argument at all?

Comment: What you're looking for doesn't seem possible atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *seems* the issue is a limitation of Typescript inference capabilities with respect to generic types - Typescript does not keep track all inferable constraints. Definitely there are some tradeoffs in doing so.

For a concrete type the inference works as expected:

```
const props: SearchListProps<DataExample> = {
  data: example_data,
  sort_and_filter_key: 'city', 
};

const ok_string = props.data[0][props.sort_and_filter_key];
```

In case of a generic type we need to manually give a hint to TS engine what exactly we are interested in:

```
interface SearchListProps<T> {
  data: (T &  Record<KeysMatching<T, string>, string>)[];
  sort_and_filter_key: KeysMatching<T, string>;
}
```

Interestingly we can intersect `T` with anything else - for example `Record<KeysMatching<T, string>, number>`, but then we are not able to initialise `SearchListProps` with a concrete type.

A fixed and simplified version:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x4jdez

Btw. `props.data[0][props.sort_and_filter_key]` is unsafe ([noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess)].

Answer (score 0):

We could also give `ItemDataT` the constraint `Record<K, string>` where `K` is just constrained as `string`.

```
class SearchList<
  ItemDataT extends Record<K, string>, 
  K extends string
> extends Component<SearchListProps<ItemDataT, K>> {
    constructor(props: {
        data: ItemDataT[],
        sort_and_filter_key: K
    }) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

When we now access `props.data[0][props.sort_and_filter_key]`, TypeScript still displays the type as `ItemDataT[K]`. **But** TypeScript actually knows that this must be a `string` this time. All the string methods are available. The type is only displayed *"wrong"* but behaves correctly.

```
const value = props.data[0][props.sort_and_filter_key]; 

value.charAt(0)
// this was compile time error before
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkifAL5wBmURcA5FKhowNwBQ3MAnmEjgBpJLwDOAWRQw0AC2AkA5gB4AKtgBqAPjgBeXJzhG4AbSFwFcANaiINOKoC6AWgD8ALgdnHcJAA8YcgATMTgNOFdhOE8yADckKE5KExteOwdHLk4FQKgadEEAZVQoOQAZYDEYAAV6MDE1XwDg0IgAIwArJAxsc39AkhDrW3tVHRxDYyDpFE9VE0zJozFoGAB9FEG1mmAAG1y11M8hLkpuNF2UMVDilFLZCqrlAElAkAARGdUmgaHkNGgQWUQmwVSgCkUWl6PxacDBEJ0-VhhGIZAoylu90eNTqDVeSA%20X16WnG3GMcABJDBAFcMNAABRgXGeCbk8nTGCzOD4wmc%20aOTBLNkrWAbLY7fYJQ6iY5CygASgMbOMYmpAigjNx8qyyqMlKqcFiKF21ME%20iZEHqADoOSgTAAGRwmC3WkXrTZBbZ7A6pTJwAD0-u5b0%20fO8cGcOjEsgg1N2QTgbUE8KUQvJgfJAD1XGTdUaTUgrXI7gBBGD0%203yuVJbgZ-zgXaCNBXJCebg5BL5NCCUMoACifhQDcErOMJCHrbhMHBSmwQrQwD4nhTikF5OAQRi1JASaga%20MlIGME87S6GCFdZkNc4%20vg-iHYEba1tnl7A4fjYWelMQtHyvHICTgARFcQRAfuyoLkucBAW0aAkOBabGBungAIwQWyh7kMeuBnOSlAYX%20bIAcBQRWIoiG6hSi68J4QEkPGlG6ihcAAEwYeSWEUCyeHGGcizcDQ1IkBgwCkHAgRVPS8pESwMDUlAJBwPSSFGBiJTlJU8C2roOD3sOz4zNQbpip6Eo%20qIulAVBvBAZQWjKP6mKaVUWhClWZxAA)